# Android Image above ListView?

Tags: android, image, listview

I have a ListView whit two taps underneath it, but i cant seem to figure out how to put an Image above the ListView. I have tried just putting an ImageView on top, but it wont do it?

This is how it looks now.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF">

<ImageView
    android:id="@drawable/frederiksberg"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what you exactly want? and what have you tried? Share it here

Comment: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and run

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/add" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

It is working fine for me. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have tried this sulution, but it wont work. No Image to be seen.

Comment: I have just Copied and pasted here, at my side it is working, have you given proper image path

Comment: Im not sure what went wrong before, but this works fine now :) I just have one problem about this, above and underneath my image there is a white line. Can i remove them in some way ?

Comment: I can see that it is because there is a background behind the image. Can i remove it in some way, or get the image to fill out the whole space ?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple dude.

Take a Linear layout L1.

add one ImageView in L1 with Weight tag = 1 
and add listview in L1 whose width and height must be fill parent.

make orientation of L1 as vertical..

let me know if any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

here is solution make your parent layout as relative layout because it will provide you more flexiblity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="122dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

hope it will work for you.. it is complete xml file i am posting for you try it.

Comment: Thank You Bharat Sharma. Can i simply replace my LiniearLayout with the RelativeLayout, without messing the whole thing up ?

Comment: no actually if you look in my code, i have set listview below to image view. This will allow your listview to always below to your imageview. This type of alignments are allowed in relative layouts only so always try to create your views on relative layouts...

Comment: ya its ok there are several ways to do same thing... Choose who fits.. :)